# W action of Schubert varieties

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, schubert-calculus

Let $X(w)$ be a Schubert variety in $G/B$, where $G$ is a semisimple algebraic group and $B$ is a Borel in $G$. Then for $v \in W$, what is $v X(w)$ ? Is it same as $X(vw)$ ?

Comment: Are you asking for the definition or whether the definitions happens to agree with it being $X(vw)$? The definition is just as you would expect, given that the Weyl group elements have representatives in $G$ up to an element of $T$ and thus $W$ has a well-defined action on $G/B$.

Comment: In general $vX(w)$ and $X(vw)$ have different dimension.

Comment: But how are $vX(w)$ and $X(vw)$ related as varieties ?